# Android Application stopped when checking future date

Tags: android, parsing

I am developing an Android app which sends the SMS at specified time. But when i check do the validation on date to check if its the future date, the application stops.The error pops up when i activate the code with in the comments.

```
package com.example.sked;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.AlarmManager;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.DatePicker;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TimePicker;

import android.widget.Toast;



public class ScheduleActivity extends Activity
{
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

        final int year_set=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int month_set=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int day_set=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        final int hr_set=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        final int min_set=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        final   DatePicker dp_c = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        final   TimePicker tp_c = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        dp_c.updateDate(year_set, month_set, day_set); //Setting current date in date picker //

        tp_c.setCurrentHour(hr_set);  //Setting current time in time picker //
        tp_c.setCurrentMinute(min_set);


        //For Scheduling a message//
        final Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_message);
        {
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {


            // Processing the input values from the user//  
            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reci_number);
            final String phno= text .getText().toString();

            EditText text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
            final String msg= text1.getText().toString();

            if(phno.length()==10)//Checking length of the mobile number//
            {
            if(msg.length()<=160 && msg.length()>0) //Checking length of the message//
            {


            DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);//Getting selected date values// 
            int day = dp.getDayOfMonth();
            int month = dp.getMonth() + 1;
            int year = dp.getYear();

            TimePicker tp=(TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);//Getting selected time values//
            int hours= tp.getCurrentHour();
            int minutes= tp.getCurrentMinute();


            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();//Getting Current date values//

            final int year_curr=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            final int month_curr=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day_curr=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            final int hr_curr=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);//Getting Current time values//
            final int min_curr=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            //String curr_values = year_curr + "-" + month_curr + "-" +day_curr+ "-"+ hr_curr + "-" +min_curr;

            //String sel_values = year + "-" + month + "-" +day+ "-"+ hours + "-" +minutes;

            //DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YY-MM-HH-mm-ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

            //try {
                //if (df.parse(sel_values).after(df.parse(curr_values)))//Checking if its the future date//
                //{



                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsNumber", phno);
                    bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsText", msg);
                    myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ScheduleActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

                int year_act=year-year_curr;
                int year_act_indays=year_act*365;
                long year_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(year_act_indays, TimeUnit.DAYS);

                int mon_act=month-month_curr;
                int mon_act_indays=mon_act*30;
                long mon_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(mon_act_indays, TimeUnit.DAYS);

                int day_act=day-day_curr;
                long day_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(day_act, TimeUnit.DAYS);

                int hr_act=hours-hr_curr;
                long hr_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(hr_act, TimeUnit.HOURS);

                int min_act=minutes-min_curr;
                long min_act_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(min_act, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


                long elapsedtimer_act= year_act_mil+mon_act_mil+day_act_mil+hr_act_mil+min_act_mil;

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,elapsedtimer_act, pendingIntent);

                final AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScheduleActivity.this, 0);

                //set  the dialog  
                dlgAlert.setMessage("Message successfully scheduled at the specified time & date");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Success");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                dlgAlert.create().show();




                //}
                //else 
                //{}
            //} catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                //"Please check the entered date...And enter future time. ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //  e.printStackTrace();
            //}
            }  

            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Message too long or too short .... cannot send ... :( ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Check the number Entered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }


        }

        );



        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.schedule, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Logcat Output:

```
09-12 11:53:11.259: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(779): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
09-12 11:53:11.259: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(779):   in android.widget.EditText{41764990 VFED..CL .F....I. 16,89-464,289 #7f08000d app:id/message}
09-12 11:53:11.259: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(779):   0: sent at 148929000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=148929, downTime=148829, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
09-12 11:53:12.978: D/dalvikvm(779): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 225K, 9% free 3234K/3520K, paused 33ms, total 39ms
09-12 11:53:21.018: D/AndroidRuntime(779): Shutting down VM
09-12 11:53:21.018: W/dalvikvm(779): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validateFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:264)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:312)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:365)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.sked.ScheduleActivity$1.onClick(ScheduleActivity.java:102)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 11:53:24.928: W/ResourceType(827): Skipping entry 0x106000b in package table 0 because it is not complex!
09-12 11:53:25.608: D/dalvikvm(827): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 5% free 2941K/3080K, paused 55ms, total 66ms
09-12 11:53:25.848: D/gralloc_goldfish(827): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-12 11:53:26.348: I/Choreographer(827): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: please post the logcat output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution for this to check if the difference between **current date & time values** and **selected date & time values**.If the difference is greater than **0** then its the future time.It is the simplest solution because the return type values of datepicker and timepicker is **int**.It works for **datepicker dialog** and **time picker dialog** as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validateFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:264)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:312)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:365)
09-12 11:53:21.038: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.sked.ScheduleActivity$1.onClick(ScheduleActivity.java:102)
```

The pattern character for year is lowercase `y`. So, change this

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YY-MM-HH-mm-ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

to something like

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-HH-mm-ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

(note that you seem to be missing the day-in-month there, too)

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I have done the changes you said,that was great help.Works perfectly now.